# Can't ping nor nmap my own public IP address

Tags: networking, ip, ping, nmap

I wanted to ping my own public IP address from my computer, but ping just returns:

```
PING (MY IP GOES HERE) ((MY IP GOES HERE)) 
56(84) bytes of data.
```

Also, when I nmap my IP I got:

> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
>   Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.14 seconds

So, I just cant do anything with my IP address from what I see now, I can surely do It with my local IP (192....), but not with the public one. Can anyone explain me why cant I ping nor nmap my own address?

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your firewall is blocking ICMP echo request (ping) requests on your public IP address. If you're connecting through a router to the internet, probably this system is running the firewall.

Nmap does a little bit more than only trying to ping, it also checks for services running on Port 443 or 80 (HTTPs and HTTP):

> If no host discovery options are given, Nmap sends an ICMP echo request, a TCP SYN packet to port 443, a TCP ACK packet to port 80, and an ICMP timestamp request. (For IPv6, the ICMP timestamp request is omitted because it is not part of ICMPv6.) [Nmap Host Discovery](https://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html)

If there is also no response to that packets, Nmap does no scan on this system. You can force Nmap to scan the IP with the `-Pn` option.